# Can't run command "code" in WSL Ubuntu. Path problem

Tags: visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently installed wsl 2 on Windows 10. Got it running and also connected VSCode to wsl. Problem is from the terminal itself the "code" command to open VSCode doesn't work: "Command 'code' not found, did you mean:". From what I researched it has to do with not "adding VSCode to your path when it was installed". I'm not really sure what this means or how to fix it (I'm a beginner), and can't find a solution to the problem online. How should I solve this?

Comment: [This](https://www.architectryan.com/2018/03/17/add-to-the-path-on-windows-10/) is how you add something to the path on Windows. Find where VSCode is stored and put the file path in the "Path".

Comment: @wxz is right, but if you have any trouble with that and just want the "lazy" solution, you can always just uninstall VSCode, then reinstall and make sure the "Add to path" option is selected.  Sadly, it can take less time to do that than it can to manually set the path.  That said, you *should* learn how to manually set the Windows path, anyway.

Comment: Thanks for both answers, I added it manually like the guide in the link said, but had no results, then I reinstanlled VSCode with the Add to Path option checked and it worked, I got curious and went to check the Path by myself to see what I did wrong when I did it manually, and apparently VSCode put it in the Path under user variables instead of system variables like the guide said. Idk it had to be in user, but it worked out anyway. Thanks again.